# ActionController::UrlGenerationError in Book#new

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

```
    I getting the following error while I am accessing my new method like http://127.0.0.1:3000/book/new
```

My project name is LibraryWebProject I am Using Eclipse with rails plugins

`routes.rb` file is

```
    LibraryWebProject::Application.routes.draw do
      get 'book/new'
      get 'book/list'
      get 'book/edit'
      get 'book/show_subjects'
      get 'book/show'
    end
```

my controller is

`book_controller.rb` controller contains the all methods. I used Mysql database and gem is `mysql2`

```
    class BookController < ApplicationController
       def list
          @books = Book.find(:all)
       end
       def new
          @book = Book.new
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
       end
       def create
          @book = Book.new(params[:book])
          if @book.save
                redirect_to :action => 'list'
          else
                @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
                render :action => 'new'
          end
       end
       def edit
          @book = Book.find(params[:id])
          @subjects = Subject.find(:all)
       end

       end


    end
```

my `new.erb` file is

```
<h1>Add new book</h1>
<%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
<p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
<%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>
<p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
<%= text_field 'book', 'price' %></p>
<%= submit_tag "Create" %>
<%= end_form_tag %>
<%= link_to 'Back', {:action => 'list'} %>
```

I am Using Rails4.0.3

finally the error is

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"book"}
Extracted source (around line #2):
  <h1>Add new book</h1>
  <%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>
  <p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:
  <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>
  <p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:
```

Rails.root: D:/RailsAppsExamples/LibraryWebProject

```
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/formatter.rb:39:in `generate'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:601:in `generate'
```

.....................
what is mean by No route matches I am helpless to find the solution for this and new to rails as well as ruby

Comment: Can you add the entire error with backtrace?

Comment: here is the entire error ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"create", :controller=>"book"}):
    1: <h1>Add new book</h1>

    2: <%= form_tag :action => 'create' %>

    3: <p><label for="book_title">Title</label>:

    4: <%= text_field 'book', 'title' %></p>

    5: <p><label for="book_price">Price</label>:

  app/views/book/new.erb:2:in `_app_views_book_new_erb__586260966_11670096'


  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-4.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9

Comment: so where is the route for your create action?

Comment: The route should be  in routes.rb is it correct get 'book/new/create' or get 'book/create'

Comment: neither. You should read up on resource routing in Rails - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default

Comment: In fact, an entire Rails tutorial probably wouldn't go astray - http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Comment: ok thank you I used  get 'book/create'

Comment: when I click the button its showing error again Started POST "/book/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-18 13:52:04 +0530

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [POST] "/book/create"):
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.0.3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:67:in `block in tagged'

Comment: because you're not using proper routing still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your route is wrong

simply replace with

```
LibraryWebProject::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
end
```

Comment: I added LibraryWebProject::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :books
end but its giving me this error No route matches [GET] "/book/new"

Rails.root: D:/RailsAppsExamples/LibraryWebProject actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (4.0.3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.0.3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'

Comment: because it's no longer 'book', it's 'books' as it should be.

Comment: Is controller should be plural form ??as you saild like books instead of book